# Como saber se um processo esta em execucao no windows usando c# ou .bat?

Tags: c#, c++

Eu estou querendo criar uma aplicacao que rode em background e que monitore algum servico para saber se esta em execucao ou nao alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Por que tem C++ nas tags?

Comment: e quase a mesma coisa as duas

Comment: Na verdade, elas são muito diferentes, apesar do nome parecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando C#, você pode usar a classe `Process`. Veja no exemplo abaixo onde verifico se o bloco de notas está aberto

```
Process[] processos = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

if (pname.Length == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Notepad NÃO está sendo executado");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Notepad está sendo executado");
```

Também é possível recuperar todos os processos que estão em execução

```
Process[] processos = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(var p in processos)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processo: {p.ProcessName} ID: {p.Id}");
}
```

Comment: o meu compilador esta com problema mas arrumarei um tempo para testar so gostaria de tirar outra duvida no caso eu teria que colocar dentro de um while ja que eu quer que fique rodando em background e um if ctrl+d se quiser fechar nao e mesmo? outra coisa essa classe Process ela pertence a api do windows?

Comment: A primeira resposta é sim. Se você quiser algo que fique verificando, terá que fazer um loop. A segunda é não, `Process` é uma classe do .NET, como ela faz por "baixo dos panos" eu já não sei dizer.

Answer (score 0):

Em C#, é só você utilizar a biblioteca Diagnostics do proprio windows.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processo = Process.GetProcessesByName("nomeDoProcesso");
if (processo.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine("Seu processo está rodando!");
```

Repare entretanto, que a maioria dos processos tem o ".exe" no final, mas você não deve utilizar isso. Por exemplo, no gerenciador de tarefas está: "firefox.exe", mas no GetProcessesByName() você deve utilzar somente "firefox".

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
```

Já em algum arquivo .bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
TASKLIST /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1" | FIND /I "%1" > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo PROCESSO RODANDO
```

Depois é só executar o .bat com o nome do processo, e caso algum processo seja encontrado será printado no cmd.

```
C:\>teste.bat firefox.exe
```